# Is it better to use 'if X: Y' or 'if not X: continue Y' in for statement?

Tags: python

I have two choices of writing a Python program:

```py
for i in (iterator):
    if (statement):
        operations
```

and

```py
for i in (iterator):
    if not (statement):
        continue
    operations
```

I think that using "continue" takes more time running, but when the "operations" is actually a very long block, I feel that shorter indentation makes the code look better.

Do they differ a lot in running speed? Does one of them have better readability for most people? Or may I just choose the one I prefer?

Comment: It's purely personal preference. They are logically identical. For all intents and purposes, a `continue` statement automatically exists at the end of your for loop block.

Comment: If there is a measurable difference, a) it is a microoptimisation and not worth worrying about, b) [measure it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) if you need to know. That aside, the remainder is an opinion question, and as such off-topic. Some programmers opine that guard conditions (the second pattern) are much clearer, some think that it is an abomination against Knuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they're different. You could use which one you prefers.

Attaching below snippet to show they're quite identical

```
In [1]: %%time 
   ...: count = 0 
   ...: for i in range(10000000): 
   ...:     if i%2==0: 
   ...:         count += 1 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CPU times: user 1.11 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.11 s
Wall time: 1.11 s

In [2]: %%time 
   ...: count = 0 
   ...: for i in range(10000000): 
   ...:     if not i%2==0: 
   ...:         continue 
   ...:     count += 1 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CPU times: user 1.15 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.15 s
Wall time: 1.15 s
```

What I normally do, if the `operations` is quite long, I would prefer `if not (conditions): continue` to avoid indentations.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the 2nd method with less indent.

You could also take operations to a different function elsewhere and write:

```
results = [operation(i) for i in iterator if statement]
```

Example:

```
>>> [i+i for i in range(10) if i<5]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to clean the line containing >>>

Comment: @EmadBoctor Nope, that's a convention to indicate that you can enter the code into the Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, makes sense.